# Sound not coming out through speakers when mic is connected, only when disconnected

Tags: sound, microphone

I'm fairly new to computers, so I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do. I connected the microphone directly to the computer because my voice wouldn't register on the mic when connected to the port on the speakers. When I checked in settings, it said there was sound coming out of the speakers but I heard none. When the mic is connected and I record, my voice is recorded just fine, but I can't hear anything unless I disconnect it and then play the audio. How do I fix this? I have Ubuntu 20.04 if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

yours is not an Ubuntu problem I believe.
There are several type of jacks.
Most of Workstations have a separated jack for mic input and for sound output, while most of laptops have one single jack for headphones that combine Mic + Audio in a single jack.

I believe you're connecting your micro to a laptop single jack, and what happens is that when computers detect something connected to the audio jack, they divert the sound from the main output to the jack, as they understand that you want to listen through headphones.

However you should be able to indicate Ubuntu that you want to output the sound through another device in System Settings:

[image]

You will see that your jack connector has one or two black plastic bands separating the metal connectors. If you provide more information on your jacks and the computer you connect to, I would probably able to tell what is wrong.

Comment: I am connecting the Comica CVM-V30 LITE, and the computer I'm connecting it to is in a Lian Li Lancool II Mesh Tempered Glass eATX case, if that helps. Is there any specific information you need? Like I said, I don't know much about computers, so I'm not sure what else might help you.

Comment: Yes, the Comica CVM-V30 LITE is a professional micro and the jack is like the ones of the headset, so I'm nor surprised that the computer tries to divert the audio to there. Go to settings and select Input device the Microphone and for Output device whatever you was using before like in the screenshot above. Press Test to hear it. Should work.